# Correct usage of should/would

Tags: should, would

Which one is correct? "Would you have any question please contact us", or "Should you have any question, ...." Or none of the twoo , but there is a different solution.

Comment: "Should" (or "If") and "questions" should be plural

Comment: Singular and plural are both correct though plural may be more usual.

Comment: "Should you" is more formal and often used in a business/legal context. In short, it replaces "if."

Answer (score 2):

Correct: "Should you have any questions, please contact us."

There's no question of *would*, because the construction requires *should*.

Rewritten, it'd be: "If you (should) have any questions, please contact us."

If you choose to begin the sentence with *should*, which is another way of writing the same, "if" can be dropped and inversion is applied as "Should you...".

Some more examples:

Should you agree with the terms and conditions, please sign.
Should it rain, we would cancel the plan.

Answer (score 0):

***Should*** you have any question, please contact us - is the correct phrase to use in your example.

Would is more of a request than a suggestion or prompt, and not suitable in this case imho.

You could rephrase the above as:

If you have any question, you **should** contact us

and if you use would instead, it doesn't make a lot of sense:

If you have any question, you **would** contact us (???)